# Alexa can turn my TV on and off, but can't access any other functions

Tags: alexa, samsung-smartthings

I've got a Samsung smart TV connected to my Echo through SmartThings.  I can turn it on off with my Echo, along with my web connected home theatre amp, but none of the other TV voice commands work.  Whenever I ask Alexa to play or pause my TV, I get the response of "TV doesn't support that".

The model number for my TV is UN65NU8000F, which according to my research should be fully supported.  The documentation for the Alexa Skill says that 2018 and 2019 model year TVs (the second N in the model number indicates that it is a 2018 model, and it was purchased near the end of 2018) support more voice commands beyond on and off, and the virtual controller in the SmartThings app also supports more functions.

I've tried both SmartThings skills (apparently they still have the SmartThings Classic skill available) with no difference between the two in functionality.  I've also made sure that the TV is named consistently in both SmartThings and Alexa.  Re-adding the TV to Alexa didn't change anything either.

It seems like I'm missing something obvious here, but have no idea what it is.  What do I have to do to enable more voice commands for my TV?

Update: it seems like SmartThings is treating my TV like a light switch question mark?  I discovered this when connecting my SmartThings account to IFTTT, with my TV listed in the "Switches" category and there being no obvious other category for it.  Is the Echo grabbing these same categories and list of available commands as IFTTT?

Comment: As an aside, I'm disappointed that the TV needs to be connected over WiFi in order for me to be able to turn it on, especially since I have an ethernet run right there.

Comment: a USB ethernet dongle might work for wakeup

Comment: @jsotola The TV has both built in wifi and ethernet.  Powering off is not a problem with either connection, but powering on can only be done over wifi, which IMHO is a stupid restriction that Samsung just hasn't put enough thought into to solve.  But the bigger problem is that's all I can do through Alexa.  I can't play or pause, change channels or inputs, or anything else on the TV.